# What is an impedance in AC circuit? (Preferred simple answer)

Tags: impedance, power-electronics

Can someone please help me understand what an impedance in AC circuit, please? I have read so much about it still I having time understand it.

How does it affect the circuit, is it good or bad for the circuit? I am just totally lost when it comes to impedance.

Please try to explain in simple way.

Comment: It's a resistance and/or a reactance.

Comment: you should read up about transmission lines, and the concept of maximum power transfer. That will explain how impedance is important

Comment: Impedance = resistance that is based on frequency. There isn't anything inherently good or bad about it. It just explains how a component allows current to flow in certain situations. For example, if you look at the equation for capacitor reactance (fancy name), you will see a "1/frequency" part in there. So, the impedance decreases with increasing frequency.

Comment: If you've already read so much about it, I don't see how asking such a tremendously broad question here is going to be any more illuminating.

Comment: It's not really a resistance based on frequency, since any reactive component will not dissipate power like a resistor would.

Comment: Good point, I was trying to keep it very basic for OP. "Resistance" has a real world connection, it can be understood when you resist something. Reactance doesn't really, it is more theoretical and maybe that is what is confusing OP.

Answer (score 1):

Impedance is a complex number that is the ratio between a (phasor) voltage and a (phasor) current in an AC circuit.

$$Z=\frac{V}{I}$$

For a two terminal element, the impedance is the ratio between the voltage across the terminals and the current through the element.

Remember that when we divide complex numbers, the magnitude of the result is given by dividing the magnitudes of the dividend and the divisor

$$|Z|=\frac{|V|}{|I|}$$

and the phase of the result is given by subtracting the phase of the divisor from the phase of the dividend

$$\angle{Z} = \angle{V}-\angle{I}$$

So the impedance specifies both the ratio between the magnitudes of V and I, but also the phase difference between the V and I waveforms.

Whether it's good or bad depends on what element it describes and how it's used in a circuit. For example, we usually want a voltage amplifier to have high input impedance and low output impedance. In a filter, we usually want the impedance of each element to be "just right" (not too high or too low or in the wrong phase) to interact with the other elements to pass or block certain frequencies.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very high-level description.

Impedance is the combination of Resistance and Reactance.

Resistance is seen as the opposition to current flow.  With any given voltage, the current flow will decrease as the resistance increases.  This is shown in Ohm's law: \$V=I\cdot R\$, rearranged to \$I=V/R\$.  Resistance dissipates power; that is, it creates heat.

Reactance is the opposition to the **change** in current or voltage.  You see this in inductors (opposing change in current) and capacitors (opposing changes in voltage).  Except for parasitic losses, Reactance doesn't consume power.  The power is simply stored in an electric field (for caps) or a magnetic field (inductors), to be released later.

In a DC circuit, at steady-state, reactance doesn't play any role because there are no changes in voltage or current.

With AC, it is always changing.  Imaging that you are feeding AC to an inductive load.  As the voltage goes up, the current doesn't increase right away because it is being opposed by the inductance.  So, the change in current always "lags" the change in voltage.

For capacitance, it is opposite.  We would say that the current "leads" the voltage.  In fact, you can use one to cancel out the effects of the other.

As far as good/bad, that depends on what you want to do!  Both effects can be useful, but sometimes they are unwanted...

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

in ac circuit, consideration of resistance isn't enough.u have to think about reactive elements.so what is reactive element? it is also a passive component but it doesn't dissipate energy.capacitor and inductor are reactive element.capacitor creates voltage inertia and inductor creates current inertia.for example you are providing 5 amp peak ac current from a current source to a circuit having resistor and capacitor and u will expect that when the current is at peak, voltage drop at the circuit should also be at peak.but u will see that it is not, rather voltage will be at peak after some time when the current is not at peak.that means the capacitor is really creating some inertia by not letting the voltage to be at its max value when it should be.And the capacitor will discharge when the source voltage will be less than that of capacitor .so for ac circuit u have to consider presence of reactive element along with resistive element.which is represented mathematically by impedance.

Answer (score 0):

**Impedance=complex resistance**

A complex resistance produces - other than an ohmic resistor - a frequency-dependent phase shift between the driving voltage and the resulting current

Example: A series connection of a resistor R and a capacitor C has the

**Impedance: Zs=R+1/jwC=R-j/wC**.

**Example**: The current through a series connection of a resistor R and a capacitor (impedance 1/jwC) causes two voltage drops which cause a phase angle "phi"between the current I and the total voltage V across the series connection. Let`s find this angle "phi":

We have **Vr=I*R and Vc=I(1/jwC)=-I(j/wC).**

Hence, the total voltage is

**V=Vr+Vc=I(R-j/wC)**.

And the angle between V and I is

**phi=arctan(Im/Re)=arctan(-1/wRC).**

The angle "phi" is alway negative (V lags I). The actual value of "phi" depends on the parts values and the operating frequency - and is always between 0 and -90deg.

Comment: @ Phil Frost, Leon Heller, Andy aka, Scott Seidman, Daniel Grillo: Impedance is an effect which is at the very heart of electronics, making the question - in my opinion - very much on topic, so the job here isn't to whine about how tough the question is to answer and sweep it under the rug, it's (perhaps) about formulating an answer, using analogy, which is understandable by the OP.  For that reason, I believe the question should be reopened.